# Laravel mixed get Eloquent eager loading nested with multiple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

The scene is: I have a user model, a Role model and a Permission model with Many to Many and one to many relationships.

User model (you can see role one to many relationship, permission many to many relationship):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Model Traits
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    use Notifiable;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Model configuration (extended from parent)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be eager loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['role', 'permissions'];

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Model Relationships
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
    }

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission');
    }
}
```

Role model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use GeneaLabs\LaravelModelCaching\Traits\Cachable;

class Role extends Model
{
    use Cachable;

    protected $with = ['permissions'];

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Model Relationships
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission');
    }
}
```

Permission model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use GeneaLabs\LaravelModelCaching\Traits\Cachable;

class Permission extends Model
{
    use Cachable;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Model configuration (extended from parent)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Campos autorellenables para la generación automática de modelos
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Model Relationships
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission');
    }
}
```

If I call `User::with(['role', 'permissions'])->get()` or even `User::with(['role.permissions', 'permissions'])->get()` I get the user data, the role data and permission data. Everything is OK, except, the role permissions are never loaded. So I cannot work with them without adding another query for this user role permission.

I know that the role have permissions 'cause when I execute `Role::where('id', 3)->with('permissions')->get();`the relationship works and has the permission data.

What I am doing wrong?

My DB tables are: users, permissions, roles, permission_role and permission_user.

**Edit** - This is the result I get from the statement:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "role_id": 3,
    "name": "UserName",
    "email": "username@domain.com",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "created_at": "2018-12-10 13:04:00",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-10 13:04:00",
    "role": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Editor",
      "created_at": "2018-12-10 13:03:31",
      "updated_at": "2018-12-10 13:03:31",
      "permissions": []
    },
    "permissions": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Delete post",
        "created_at": "2017-10-23 11:07:43",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-23 11:07:43",
        "pivot": {
          "user_id": 1,
          "permission_id": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, permissions of the role are empty.

Comment: Would you need a 'hasManyThrough' relationship instead? A user has many permissions through a role?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. It was a problem with the cached models. Flushing cache `php artisan cache:clear`solved it right.